# How to use fasttext in rasa nlu with docker

Tags: chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I have developed a chatbot using [this](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/running-rasa-with-docker/) with docker. it's working fine, and now I want to implement it in Hindi. I found that we can do that with fasttext followed [this blog](https://medium.com/strai/build-a-rasa-nlu-chatbot-with-spacy-with-fasttext-240e192082bd) but unable to achieve. so how I can implement fasttext in rasanlu with docker?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your bot in Hindi with Rasa even without using Fasttext. The [`supervised_embeddings` pipeline](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/choosing-a-pipeline/#supervised-embeddings) works out of the box for any whitespace tokenized language (which as far as I know is the case for Hindi). Read more about language support [here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/language-support/)

Alternatively, if you still want to use fasttext, that can be done since spacy allows you to load custom language models. If the blogpost isn't working for you, you can take a look at this [github issue](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/issues/869).

There's also a bunch of Rasa community members that have built bots in hindi, you can take a look at this in the [community forum](https://forum.rasa.com/search?q=hindi) and see if they have any additional tips.